# Difference between release and dealloc in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, memory

When deallocing a refrence I've seen `release` and `dealloc` being used for example

```
-(void)dealloc
{
  [foo release];
  [nar dealloc];

  [super dealloc];
}
```

My question is when is `release` to be used and when is `dealloc` to be used?

Thanks

Comment: If you call `[self dealloc]` inside the `-dealloc` definition, then it will result in a recursion. Are you sure the code is correct?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Never call `dealloc` except as `[super dealloc]` at the end of your class's `dealloc` method. The `release` method relinquishes ownership of an object. When a Cocoa object no longer has any owners, it may be deallocated — in which case it will automatically be sent a `dealloc` message.

If you're going to program Cocoa, you need to read the [Memory Management Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html). It's incredibly simple once you get over the initial hump, and if you don't understand what's in that document, you'll have lots of subtle bugs.

Comment: what about [self dealloc] as I've shown in the example, is there really a need for that?

Comment: Not only is it unnecessary, calling [self dealloc] in your dealloc method creates an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

The `dealloc` statement in your example is called when the object's retain count becomes zero (through an object sending it a release message).

As it is no longer needed, it cleans itself up by sending a `release` message to the objects that it is holding on to.

Answer (score 1):

You're never supposed to call dealloc explicitly (unless it's [super dealloc] within the dealloc method, but that's the only exception). Objective-C handles memory management via reference counting, so you're simply supposed to match your allocs/retains with releases/autoreleases and let the object deconstruct itself.