# iphone release dealloc

Tags: iphone, class, release, instance, dealloc

I wish best understand the difference between dealloc and release function....
example...
I have my class derived from NSObject calle MyClass
in my code, to use this class, I create an instance of MyClass..

```
// initialization
MyClass* test = [[MyClass alloc] init];

//do some stuff....

// release??
[ test release];
```

is right?? and the dealloc??? needs to be used in sequency or one overwrite the other??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between release and dealloc in objective-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559295/difference-between-release-and-dealloc-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dealloc is automatically called when retainCount is  == 0. Each time you call [test release] the retainCount is decreased by one.

In your example everything is fine, since you have alloc test (retain count +1) and then release (retain count 0). Dealloc will be automatically called

Comment: in your example you have two instances, each one with a retain count +1

Comment: ok, but can you write me an example where you have retainCount = 2 and what is the usage of this thing??
thanks very much noya!
p.s. ho visto che sei italiano!!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

As long as that's the end of `test`'s life, you're correct.  Dealloc of `test` will automatically happen as a function of your `[ test release]` statement.